# Custom ngmodel binding after ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm writing a custom angular2 component that using Custom ngModel.

The problem i'm facing is ngModel will be bound after another binding like "@input". For example on the same method, i change value for ngModel and value for @input. Inside the child component, i need to handle if any change happens at ngOnChanges. But that seesm the value for @input has changed, but the value for ngModel is still the old value ( i need to get the new value here for some validation)

Here is demo on plunker:

```
## https://plnkr.co/edit/U6eSZ6GJB6HvHADLyEG2?p=preview ##
```

Waiting for some ideas. 
Thanks.

Comment: Pls set the link right and add the relevant parts of the code to the question.

Comment: That is how it works. What is that you are trying? your explanation is not clear.

Comment: @Aravind, sorry for my bad english. The idea is like: 
The father component has 2 properties "value and maxinum(the value for "ngmodel" and maxinum for "@Input") " and will pass them to a child component. After that the same time the father component will changeto pass them to child component.
The child component which has 2 properties: value and maxinum.
I used ngOnChange to detect changes inside child comonent. But ngOnChange just detect that maxinum (@maxinum) has changed, the value (for Ngmodel) is still the old. Plz, take a look inside on plunker link.

Comment: @surai....sorry for that inconvenient. The first time i post on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the changes in one place and do validation there. 
Create two subjects for model and maximum, push change there and combine the observables for validation.

```
   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      alert("current model " + this.value + "--- current maxinum " + changes.maximum.currentValue);
      this.maximum$.next(this.maximum);
   }

   //From ControlValueAccessor interface
   writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
        this.model$.next(value);
        this.innerValue = value;
    }
  }

  Observable.combineLatest(this.maximum$, this.model$).
    subscribe(validateHere)
```

Comment: That's still same problem.

Form father component, i change "maximum" and "value" in the same method. So the flow of angular process is:
- call ngOnchanges firstly, then call "validateHere" method (based on your code)
- call writeValue secondly, then call "validateHere" method again (based on your code)

=> the prolem here is: when ngOnChanges is called, value is still old (not yet update untill writeValue method is called). So validateHere method will run with out of update value.